# GFCI mystery interaction with room lights

Tags: gfci, led

I have one GFCI for all bathroom outlets and outdoor outlets. By a process of elimination, I have identified one outdoor outlet that is causing the GFCI to trip. But the strange thing is that the GFCI only trips when the downstairs room lights are off; it works fine when the room lights are on.

Any idea what could be causing this odd behavior? The room lights are on a separate breaker, and were recently changed from incandescent to LEDs.

Comment: Have you fixed/replaced the outdoor outlet yet?  When does the outdoor outlet trip the GFCI, in use only or anytime?

Comment: @crip659  The GFCI trips when the outdoor outlet is not in use. I will fix the outdoor outlet once I understand the interaction.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is the lights on, are bleeding off enough of the ground fault so it does not trip.  Do think it is weird and should not happen.  Usually with LEDs they will react weirdly to other stuff, not cause other stuff to react weirdly to them.

Comment: I suppose another way to state this is that having the room lights on prevents the GFCI from tripping as it should. Crazy, eh?